# What regex engine does mod_substitute use?

Tags: apache

Any idea what regex engine mod_substitute uses?  I'd like to do a little search and replace with it, and I need to escape some characters, so I wanted to see how that particular engine handles that.  (I'm guessing it's just `\` to escape, but I wanted to know for sure.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Apache universally uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE). This is stated in [the Apache glossary under Regular Expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/glossary.html#regex). mod_rewrite certainly uses PCRE (as stated in the mod_rewrite docs) and I would assume that mod_substitute does the same.

The backslash (`\`) escape is used in every regex version I've encountered.

Note that the `Substitute` directive uses delimiters to separate the different arguments (whereas mod_rewrite uses spaces). The default delimiter is the slash (`/`), but this can be changed to any other character if your string/regex contains the delimiter. Changing the delimiter is often preferable to escaping these characters in the string/regex.