# Simple .htaccess language question (redirection)

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I do not know the language of .htaccess, thus the newbie question. I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=1$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

It redirects any urls that have this extension `?m=1` to the url without the extension.

I would like to redirect also `?m=0` (or `?m=anything` ) to the original url. How should I re-write the above code?
Would that just be `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=*$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is as much a question about regular expressions (regex) than `.htaccess`. The second argument (*CondPattern*) to the `RewriteCond` directive takes a regex, not a *wildcard* expression. (Specifically, [Apache uses the PCRE *flavour* of regex](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/92471/1243).)

> Would that just be `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=*$`

No. This assumes the argument is a simpler *wildcard* type expression (where `*` simply matches 0 or more characters) - it is not. In regex-speak, the `*` matches 0 or more occurrences of the *preceding character/group*. So, this would match exactly `?m` (0 occurrences), `?m=` (1 occurance), `?m==` or `?m===`, etc. Not your intention at all. It wouldn't even match your original URL.

Assuming the `m` URL parameter always occurs at the start of the query string, then to match `?m=<anything>`, you could simply use the regex `^m=`. This matches any query string that starts `m=` followed by *anything* (including *nothing*). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=
```

However, you generally want regex to be as restrictive as possible (although that may not apply in this case). For example, to match any URL that contains the query string `?m=N` only, where N is a digit 0-9 and there are no other URL parameters, then you could do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=\d$
```

Where `\d` is a shorthand character class for any digit (the same as `[0-9]`).

*Aside:* Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching problems and clear your browser cache before testing.